# What is the One Piece's "Episode of Nami" categorized as?

Tags: one-piece

The One Piece's "Episode of Nami" is not an anime episode because of its length. What is that episode categorized as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Episode of Nami: Tears of a Navigator and the Bonds of Friends is a **TV Special** of the One Piece anime. It aired after Episode 560.

*(From the One Piece wiki [Episode of Nami](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_of_Nami))*

It is the 5th TV special to be aired. The list of TV specials so far:

1. [Adventure in the Ocean's Navel](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Special_1)
2. [Open Upon the Great Sea! A Father's Huge, HUGE Dream!](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Special_2)
3. ["Protect! The Last Great Performance"](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Special_3)
4. [The Detective Memoirs of Chief Straw Hat Luffy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Special_4)
5. [Episode of Nami: Tears of a Navigator and the Bonds of Friends](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_of_Nami)
6. [Episode of Luffy: Adventure on Hand Island](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_of_Luffy)